# R Loop list creation

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create a bunch of vectors in R with a loop as follows:

```
    dlist <- c('"lnincome", "retprice", "age15to24"',
           '"retprice", "age15to24", "beer"',
           '"retprice", "age15to24"',
           '"retprice", "beer"',
           '"lnincome", "beer"')

    for (i in 1:length(dlist)) {
output_[[i]]<-dataprep(foo = smoking, 
                     predictors = c(cat(dlist[i])),
                     predictors.op = c("mean"),
                     special.predictors = list(
                       list("cigsale", 1988, "mean"),
                       list("cigsale", 1980, "mean"),
                       list("cigsale", 1975, "mean")
                     ),
                     dependent = c("cigsale"),
                     unit.variable = "statenum",
                     time.variable = c("year"),
                     treatment.identifier = 3,
                     controls.identifier = c(1:2, 4:39),
                     time.predictors.prior = c(1980:1988),
                     time.optimize.ssr = c(1975:1988),
                     time.plot = c(1975:2000),
                     unit.names.variable = c("state")
              )

#assign( paste("test_", eval(i), sep="") , output)
synth.out_[[i]]<-synth(output_i)
#assign( paste("synth_", eval(i), sep="") , synth.out)

path.plot(dataprep.res = output_i, synth.res = snyth.out_i)
    rm(synth.out, test)

    }
```

However, when the loop runs, I get an error that reads "object 'test_' not found.  How do I make it so that the object test_1 is created on the first iteration of the loop, then the object test_2, until test_n (n=5, here).

Then, how do I call those created values of output_i and synth_i in my path.plot function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the function `get()`

Such as

```
get(paste("output_", i, sep=""))
```

I generally would advise you not to make so many variables, but rather place them in a named list. For this you could update the following.

```
output_ <- list()
synth.out_ <- list()
   for (item in dlist) {
output_[paste(item)]<-dataprep(foo = smoking, 
                 predictors = c(cat(dlist[i])),
                 predictors.op = c("mean"),
                 special.predictors = list(
                   list("cigsale", 1988, "mean"),
                   list("cigsale", 1980, "mean"),
                   list("cigsale", 1975, "mean")
                 ),
                 dependent = c("cigsale"),
                 unit.variable = "statenum",
                 time.variable = c("year"),
                 treatment.identifier = 3,
                 controls.identifier = c(1:2, 4:39),
                 time.predictors.prior = c(1980:1988),
                 time.optimize.ssr = c(1975:1988),
                 time.plot = c(1975:2000),
                 unit.names.variable = c("state")
          )


synth.out_[paste(item)]<-synth(output[paste(item)])

path.plot(dataprep.res = output[paste(item)], synth.res =     synth.out_[paste(item)])
# not sure what the last line is doing
rm(synth.out, test)
```

You don't give enough info to try it out though: what's `dataprep()`, what's `test`? PS There's a typo on the plot function `snyth.out_i`.